# working on same branch from different machine avoid conflicts

Tags: git, branch, conflict, git-branch, pull

I work from office and home from different machines. So I used to push the changes from office and pull it from home so that I don't have to copy the files. But when I pull the changes from home after pushing the updates from office, I'm getting a lot of conflicts (without editing any file from home before pull). What I do is

```
@office on branch "feature"
1. do my updates on code
2. commit
3. push to remote branch

@home on branch "feature"
1. pull (this is where I gets the conflicts)
2. resolve conflicts (why should I do this every time when I'm only the person who works on that branch)
```

The same happens when I pull the changes from office next day. I do this because I need to continue to work with the feature from home and vice verse. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: How are you creating the `feature` branch at home? What commands?

Comment: I didn't created. Just cloned the branch and used checkout

Comment: Can you run a `git log` to see your commit history on each, and verify that it should be a simple fast-forward?

Comment: What OS are you using on home and office? Do you have `core.autocrlf` set to true? what are the conflicts? eol (end of lines) diffs?

Comment: I use ubutnu in both machines. what is that `core.autocrlf` means? usual conflicts which comes when we merge two branches where same line of codes are modified.

Comment: From home, try the command `git fetch` instead of `git pull` in order to get every new commits from the remote repo. Then execute the following command: `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all -10` and paste the result here.